# How to sum BIGINT into timestamp in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two columns that looks something like this in a hive table:

```
Seconds_col       Timestamp_col
  87            2017-09-25 08:06:00.0       
  59            2017-09-25 08:10:00.0
```

I am trying to create another timestamp column that is the sum of the seconds_col + timestamp_col, but I am having problems figuring out how to sum the seconds_col which is type BIGInt into the Timestamp_col which is a timestamp column. Does anyone have any suggestion of how I could accomplish this in hive? I've been checking the date and time functions but so far all my attempts have failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved

setp 1 - covert time stamp to unix_timestamp.

step 2  -add seconds to unixtimestamp

step3  - convert back to Timestamp using from_unixtime.

```
  select  from_unixtime( unix_timestamp(Timestamp_col) + Seconds_col)
    from yourtablename
```

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep, I had tried originally transforming the timestamp to unixtimestamp and then summing the seconds but I had not tried converting it back to from_unixtimestamp. Thanks for the clarification and help!